# How can I fix my "P" key on Windows login?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

On Windows 10 login, my "P" key does not function in the password field. I can get around the problem in two ways:

- If I instead use my PIN to login, the P key works just fine once I'm actually logged-in and using applications.
- Also, if I click the "forgot password" link, Windows tries to take me to the reset password screen, BUT that screen fails and I'm returned to the login screen. At *that* point the P key *does* work.

So bizarre. It's behaved like this for four days. It happens with both the USB keyboard that came with the computer and my bluetooth Microsoft-branded keyboard. Switching keyboards mid-entry does not fix the problem, and I haven't had a problem with any other keys. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Is "P" on a Num or Shift lock?  That is one likely explanation

Comment: @John, no; it is on neither.

Comment: Shut down and try the other keyboard. Switching keyboards will not help. "P" works on my machines.

Comment: @John once again, turning it off and back on again to the rescue. No more trouble (for now, anyway), and didn't even need to switch keyboards. Garrgh. I hate that that solution is a thing.

Comment: If I post a full shut off and restart answer, will that be a solution for you?

Comment: @John definitely

Comment: I'm experiencing what I think is the same issue. What I find interesting in my case is that not only is the physical 'P' key ignored, so is the 'P' key on the onscreen keyboard - but ALT+112 is accepted. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234758-specific-letters-not-working-at-windows-10-login-screen suggests that it may be to do with the screen-select menu displayed by Windows+P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching keyboards will not help because of the native connection of the keyboard within the machine. "P" works on my machines, so try the following:   Shut down entirely, restart and check if "P" is working.  Also try a different keyboard using the same process.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an Alt code. Try holding Alt and typing 80 on the keypad (Numlock on) then let go of the Alt, that should input a "P" or 112 for "p".

https://www.alt-codes.net/

However, it sounds like it just needs a Windows "fix", aka reboot.

Comment: Nice. That solution works, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I came in in the morning and tried to log in to my computer.  I had a second keyboard, so I swapped it out and had the same issue.  Rebooting the computer fixed the problem.

Note:  Both keyboards are Logitech wireless keyboards.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced that this morning. My laptop is an HP Envy.

The letter 'p' jumped to another line. It was weird. I wrote all the numbers and the alphabet, and when I pressed 'p', it goes to the right side, and next letter 'o' would be at its left. I also wrote the numeric characters, but they showed different characters. Stopped for a while as I got stressed.

Closed the laptop and let it 'breathe' for a while. Then when I opened it, I reviewed some apps installed, uninstalled unnecessary ones.

Finally, I cleaned my keyboard with cotton and disinfectant. I read somewhere online to touch some special keys like 'shift', 'ctrl', etc a few times. I decided to just clean it gently. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very weird software bug that keeps happening to me from time to time. Only solution is reboot or use the alt code.